# How to handle city names with different names

Tags: c#, error-correction

I have the following task. I have list of bank photos which have city where it was takene. I am trying to write program that imports those. Problem is that same city could be written differently:

- easy case: REYKJAV**Í**K or Reykjav**i**k. Can be solved by invariant case-insensitive comparison.
- harder case: Lviv or Lvov - could be solved using Levenstein distance. For such cases if cities start from same letter and have distance less or equal 1 - we're ok to match.
- even harder case: Brussels vs Bruxelles.
- just another one: m.Wroclaw(read as city of Wroclaw)

In the end I need to map all those city 'synonims' to some common denominator.

Therefore my question is - can you suggest way how this can be achieved?

What have I tried:

1. case-insensitive comparison + converting to invariant - helps with case #1.
2. Levenshtein distance to see how two strings are different. Doesn't realy helps much. Distance of 3 or greater could mean this is synonym (e.g. Kyiv and m.Kiev) or absolutely different city (e.g. Řím and Rimini, both italy, same locale). Even knowing country of city doesn't help much.
3. Tried to use dictionary of cities + finding the closest term (criteria: same length and same first letter, minimal distance). Still in 7% of cases I have an error.
4. using Google places API to look for city and have it returned in one locale. Still doesn't work - Bruxelles and Brussels for google seem different, even though both located in Belgium.

Any advice would be appreciated.

P.S. Do you think there is chance correct city mapping in 99% of cases?

Comment: I doubt that there is a generic approach which handles such cases, especially if you even want to take multiple languages into account. So you need a table or dictionary to map all possible city-names for a given city. You can just use the case-insensitive comparison to reduce the amount of mappings

Comment: It seems like a translation table would be prudent here to catch the ones that are truly language differences. For instance, in English we use "Brussels" but in French and a few other languages we use "Bruxelles". I would imagine there is a source for such a thing. [Like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_of_European_cities_in_different_languages) Perhaps a table of `zip codes | name | language` with `name` being unique and zip codes repeated. Then everything can rectify to a zip and then into any language.

Comment: Any chance you could add coordinates for additional information

Comment: @TravisHerbert I can't added coordinates to photos unfortunately (because those which have are already handled by geocoding using Google Maps API). But what I can do is try to use google API to get latitude and longitude. I assume it should return same for `Brussels` and `Bruxelles`. So unique key would be lat + long

Comment: The other issue you will run into is that `Levenshtein Distance` is going to give you false matches like `Andorra` and `Andorre`.

Comment: If the data coming in is "dirty" (user-entered or from otherwise uncontrolled or not reliable sources) then #4 on your list really seems like the best bet.  Let an external service which specializes in discerning locations make a best guess at what the data is meant to pinpoint, and use the location data returned from that service.  There will always be a margin of error.  But, consider this... If *Google Maps* can't find the location accurately, how much is your company willing to invest to beat it?

Comment: @seeker I would suggest using something other than names for unique identification. Two cities can have the same name as well as one city being referred to by different names. Common names can be a dangerous identifier. Would using lat,lon work for your identification needs?

Comment: @TravisHerbert, indeed you're right. This nice case when within one country two different cities has same name... Also, after rethinking, I realized that lat+long will not be enough for identification.

Comment: @seeker - yes, unique key would be lat + long. If google API returns a slight different lat and long for provided local city names, then you can check the geodistance between two fetched lat+long. And if the distance is less than threshold then you can assume as same city.

Comment: @seeker That's unfortunate, what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @TravisHerbert my personal thought here is that hard to guess good threshold to consider lat+long unique for same city. Just checked a while ago - imagine we have distance of 45 km - is it good enough to consider match? So, in the end, I need to use some heuristic approach, some 'guessing'... As with other cases as well...

Comment: @seeker Ya i see what you mean. It might be worth checking of Google Maps API ever gives varying lat/lon for synonymous city names. Oh another thing to think about is in some countries they can be named something like alaba and alaba 1 and alaba 2. And these three cities can be relatively close. (This is a specific case I am thinking about from some time in indonesia, I am not sure how common it is)

Comment: @TravisHerbert regarding case with 'alaba' and 'alaba 1' you mean this will be a problem because maps API will return same coordinates for both? If so - we have problem. But provided Maps API will return different coordinates for those, and every time those coordinates will be stable - this is a way to go. Already trying to use API to get lat/long and will compare error rate using this approach with one I have now with current approach

Comment: @seeker sorry, I should have clarified the alaba naming issue was in reference to using name resolving for identification, not lat/lon. Keep me updated on what you find with the API for lat/lon if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

old school method of handling this was something we done back a decade or so back - create a database table with lookups.  Assuming we could identify the possible variations (not always a good assumption, but the best we had at the time) we could do a lookup and store only the 'correct' variation (as in the most common and/or the one we wanted).  This involves doing some reearch and footwork up front, but can lead to pretty good results.  And, if the database is setup properly, you can keep adding more variations as they pop up in data.

99% would be tough, since the variations are unknown.